# Git: Pulled the wrong branch, then pushed the merge. How to undo?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, branching-and-merging, git-workflow

I recently made a mistake with my git merge strategy, and didn't notice the result error(s) until I had already continued to work on the project and made more commits.  For the sake of brevity, let's say I have two branches, `hotfix` and `new_feature`.  I did something like the following:

```
git checkout new_feature
git commit -m "Commit to the feature branch"
git checkout hotfix
git pull origin new_feature # Uh oh, I pulled the wrong branch!
git commit -m "Commit to the hotfix"
git push origin hotfix # Uh Oh, pushed the bad merge!
```

After the events above, other developers also made commits to the Hotfix branch.  Now, we have a hotfix we want to push out, but can't because it contains feature work that isn't complete.

I've seen a lot of similar questions about this situation, but none that match 100% (most of them involve undoing the commit directly after the bad pull, without pushing first.  I've gone one step further, and really borked things.

Any step-by-step guides on how I can remedy this?

Thanks!

**Edit:** many other answers mention `git reflog`, so here is a modified copy of mine.  I've changed the hashes and branch names to match my example above.

```
aaaaaaa HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from new_feature to hotfix
bbbbbbb HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from hotfix to new_feature
aaaaaaa HEAD@{2}: commit: Added analytics tracking
ccccccc HEAD@{3}: commit (merge): Fixed a merge issue in compiled css # BAD MERGE?
ddddddd HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from new_feature to hotfix
eeeeeee HEAD@{5}: commit: Finished updating the events for the header
ddddddd HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from hotfix to new_feature
ddddddd HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from new_feature to hotfix
```

In the reflog above, `HEAD@{3}` looks to be the bad merge.  I was on the `hotfix` branch, and pulled in the `new_feature` branch, which gave merge conflicts.  I fixed them, and pushed.  What would I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the commit hash: `git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" | grep "Commit to the hotfix"`

Revert the "Uh oh" commit: `git revert 15d2e1f -m 2`

Comment: But there's not just one commit.  The "Uh Oh" commit was a merge from another branch, which included a bunch of commits!  I'd need to go through the Hotfix history and revert a bunch of commits, which seems a little "hacky"